# Is it possible to interact with another programs interface?

Tags: electron

In my case I want to start a program's .exe and interact with its interace to display certain views with preset data.

Is that possible (and I hope legal)?

Comment: I'm asking it in "electron" because I would do it with electron. Sorry if the question sounds stupid. I just don't find the correct terms to google for.

Comment: You would probably call the program from the nodejs side of your application and interact and display data to the electron render-side of the application using IPC

Comment: It really depends, but this doesn't sound like something widely supported. It would help if you post a specific program in mind. Maybe someone else knows, but off the top of my head you'd need to find a tool that supports controlling other programs programmatically and call that from electron.

Comment: @Phix In my specific case I want to start a video game. And in this video game I want to load a match lobby with preset settings so the user wouldn't need to set those settings. If thats not possible, maybe I can listen to events inside the game user interface and perform actions?

Comment: I really don't think that's possible in electron, or javascript in general.  That sounds more like a bot program, which would be another framework entirely, but I don't know for sure personally.